# Auto Layout: layoutMarginsGuide

Tags: ios, autolayout

How to rewrite visual format

```
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-[label]-|", options: .AlignAllBaseline, metrics: nil, views: ["label": label]))
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[label]-|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["label": label]))
```

by moving to layout guides (with margins)?

I tried it with

```
label.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).active = true
label.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor).active = true
label.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
label.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor).active = true
```

but does not work. Even `layoutMarginsGuide.layoutFrame` does not have expected value (yes I call it in `layoutSubviews` after `super` is executed). Constraints are set, but acts like there is zero margin. It layouts and gives expected `layoutFrame` only when the layout margin is set to negative; which is not what I want obviously, but demonstrates that constraints are set with margins guides. Looks like I'm missing something...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to me that layoutMarginsGuide is not ready in the init method of a UIView. I'm also getting similar issues, where setting up the constraints in updateConstraints just works. Still investigating why.

UPDATE: What I was trying to do was set the layoutMargins before the view had been added to a superview (in the init). That didn't work. What did work was setting the constraints in the init, relative to layoutMarginsGuide, but actually setting the layoutMargins in viewDidMoveToSuperView.

Comment: If you find something out, please share.

Comment: Okay... nice catch, but this does not make sense to me. In addition, new `layoutMargins` must differ in value. Same problem here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/93313. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: Would've never figured this out myself. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I had a similar problem, but without access to viewDidMoveToSuperView  in UIView I put it in `updateConstraints`, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40461444/897465

Comment: This is ridiculous, but this solves the issue. I spent a whole day trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I did some another research on that since we now have iOS 10. Here is what I found:

- It still doesn't work reliably. I mean setting constraints relative to layout margins guide in designated initializer with no further actions.
- It works fine if frame size >= layout margins for particular size.
- Else if you will call `layoutMarginsGuide` (even only in `print`, we are still talking about calls within initializer) you will corrupt this guide so even in later call (in `didMoveToWindow` for example) it will not work then. You can repair it by setting new `layoutMargins` (but new value must differ with old).

I consider this a bug and filed it (please file it as well so it can be prioritized for fix).

Comment: If you can post the Radar on OpenRadar as well, and mention your Radar number here, it's easier for us to duplicate, and less work for the Apple peeps to connect the Radars to each other. Thanks for posting this, helped me a lot!

Comment: https://openradar.appspot.com/30462133, and "It works fine if frame size >= layout margins for particular size." This works.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found out that you can setup layoutMargins in `init` as well as your constraints without any problem.

It only requires to setup

`self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

(yes, **self**)

If you don't, no constraint will break, although margins won't work (in iOS 10)

Answer (score 0):

Reusable view which contains workaround addressed `layoutMarginsGuide` issue (Swift 4).

```
open class View: UIView {

   public override init(frame: CGRect) {
      var adjustedFrame = frame
      if frame.size.width == 0 {
         adjustedFrame.size.width = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
      }
      if frame.size.height == 0 {
         adjustedFrame.size.height = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
      }
      super.init(frame: adjustedFrame)
      #if !TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
         initializeView()
      #endif
   }

   public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }

   open override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      initializeView()
   }

   open func initializeView() {
      // Do something in child classes.
   }
}
```